# Disable global fog from camera

Tags: unity, camera, unityscript

Does anyone know how to disable global fog from a particular camera?

---

I have two cameras in my scene; one is a mini map camera, where I need to disable global fog.

I have checked [this answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/11100/is-it-possible-to-disable-fog-on-a-per-camera-basi.html) and [the wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Fog_Layer), but have found nothing that works.

Comment: @Philipp Actually, it looks like the duplicates go in the other direction - this question pre-dates the one you linked.

Comment: @Pikalek Duplicates should always point to the question with the better answer(s), no matter which one got asked first.